# Assign the launchPad hotkey to another Application

Tags: shortcut-menu

I'd like to set the <kbd>launchPad</kbd> key :
[image: launchpad key image]
to the `Application windows (See all)` function but I can't manage to do it. Any clue ?

Comment: What app is that ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 the real term is `Application windows (See all)` I guess

Answer (score -1):

This isn't an ideal answer, but might be good enough:

- Go to `System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard`
- Check "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys"
- Go to `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts`
- Set F3 to "display application windows"
- Set the other functions on the f-keys to their default (e.g. whichever f-key your keyboard has for play/pause, mine is F8 will be set to iTunes Play/Pause)

This will let you set the F keys to the functions you want and you won't have to press <kbd>fn</kbd> to access them.

Comment: Did you try it ? Try to assign this F3 hotkey

Comment: It works for me. On a laptop, to get f3, you have to hold down the fn key (usually in the bottom left corner of the keyboard, or next to home if you are using an external keyboard)

Comment: Yes, precisely, it works for the F3 key, but not with the original launchpad key, I mean, you can assign `fn+f3` but not only `f3`

Comment: You can check "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" in the keyboard tab. and then assign whichever function you want to each F key

Comment: done editing ! Any new clue ?

Comment: do you use the function keys for anything else? You can always check "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" and then set f3 to what you want. (but then set all of the other f-keys to the correct function)

Comment: The keys are in the default configuration : f1 turn down the screen light, f2 turn up the light... And I don't wanna switch to the other config. Does this answer to your question ?